# Get Timezone name form Timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any way to get Timezone name from Timestamp value in BQ?

Is there any function like:

`SELECT RETRIVE_TIMEZONE(timestamp_filed) FROM table_name`

to get only `UTC` part from `2016-03-31 19:23:07 UTC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP` with format element `%Z` :

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', TIMESTAMP '2016-03-31 19:23:07 UTC') AS timezone_name
```